# How do I change text color on a single word when cell changes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, visual-basic

Please see attached photo:
In case the photo is not there:
Line 35 shows Text in all red color.
Line 36 shows Text in all black but one word is red color.

Default Setting: Red text on a single word.

I want this Action: Change entire row to black text when someone changes the text in the cell to something else. But how?

So I tried conditional formatting on lines 35 and 36, if the cell, specific text, contains, changes then the font should be black.  Line 35 works.  Line 36 does not.  For some reason the word won't change color unless ALL the font is a single color.  I tried a lighter shade black for the black, and red for the word, but that doesn't work.

I do NOT want to do a worksheet_change macro because I don't want to mess with the user not being able to use the Excel "Undo" command anytime the worksheet changes.

Any thoughts to either make a macro that doesn't affect every change/Excel undo?
Or how to work around the conditional formatting?

[image]

Comment: This doesn't make sense "if the cell, specific text, contains, changes then the font should be black". Could you edit and clarify? Apart from that, why do you need to have specific words in certain colors? If you are trying to draw attention to specific parts of speech or text, you might consider creating a column that either categorizes or flags the row according to the criteria currently being used to color that word red.

Comment: "if the cell, specific text, contains" is the conditional format menu and drop down selections.  So this would be "Conditional Formatting" menu. Drop down, "New Rule", "Format only cells that contain", "Format only cells with: Specific Text", "Not containing", Then the "not containing" is the text in the cell.

Comment: I've noticed I can use a cell that is behind the red-text-word.  Use a FILL conditional formatting.  That would create a highlight, then when the text in the A35 changes, the highlight will go away.  I'd have to resize the column width to match the word width.